# Image gets black background when downloaded as docx file

Tags: html, css, angular, docx

I had a png image of a logo,which I converted to the base64 code,this image is rendered properly with the background in the mail and print preview section that i did ,but in the download section where this image is part of the docx file,the background turns black for the image

I had created the dynamic HTML as follows

```
    <table width="650px" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="color: #434955;border-top: 10px solid #c70b5e; font-family: 'Open Sans', 'arial',' sans-serif';">
          <tr>
             <td>
                <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                   <tr>
                      <td width="70%" >
                       <img style="display: block;" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
                        <br/><br/><br/><div style="font-size: 18px;">This is the data for __Name__ below:</div>
                      </td>

 </tr>
</table>
</table>
```

what can be done so as to get a proper white background for the image instead of black background that shows up for the png image?

Comment: setting the bg-color property for the image tag helped

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following inline style on the table element..

style="background-color: #fff"

You would need to insert the image into the docx file if you wanted to preserve the transparency.

Comment: but i'm creating a dynamic html that is used across all three section for mail,print preview and download ,insert image for docx file didnt get can you please elaborate on it

Comment: setting background didnt help @lukeocom